# Não exibir valor de variável na view laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

```
    @foreach ($respostas as $resposta)

           @if($reclamacao->id == $resposta->reclamacao_id)
    
                <td>{{$resposta->resposta}}</td>
    
                {{$i++}}
    
           @endif

    @endforeach
```

Quando executo esse trecho de código é exibido na view os valores de incremento da variavél $i, sendo que só estou usando ela para controle. Alguém sabe como faço para parar de exibir esses valores?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 1):

para executar um comando php sem exibi-lo use @php

```
@foreach ($respostas as $resposta)

       @if($reclamacao->id == $resposta->reclamacao_id)

            <td>{{$resposta->resposta}}</td>

            @php 
            $i++; 
            @endphp

       @endif

@endforeach
```

Mas veja bem, está usando um foreach, logo não depende de um incremento. caso esteja usando o incremento em outro lugar que não é visível no código que disponibilizou tudo bem.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Já foi respondido, mas você também poderia usar uma maneira mais simples, usando `@php`.

Veja:

```
@foreach ($respostas as $resposta)
        @if($reclamacao->id == $resposta->reclamacao_id)
            <td>{{$resposta->resposta}}</td>
            @php($i++)
        @endif
@endforeach
```

Além de aceitar uma expressão dentro de `@php` até `@endphp`, é possível também usar apenas a chamada curta, como mostrado acima.